# Problem installing ubuntu-sdk on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 15.04, ubuntu-sdk

I'm trying to install ubuntu-sdk on my Ubuntu 15.04. I followed the steps [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/). The PPA adds perfectly fine by issuing the following command:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
```

But whenever I try to install the SDK using the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

it keeps giving me this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-sdk : Depends: ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And of course after adding the PPA and prior to trying to install the SDK, I do issue an "apt-get update" followed by an "apt-get dist-upgrade".

I tried to get to the bottom of it by attempting to install the dependencies manually all the way down to the point I reached to this:

```
# apt-get install libgles2-mesa-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgles2-mesa-dev : Depends: libgles2-mesa (= 10.5.2-0ubuntu1) but 10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~utopic is to be installed
                     Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm sure I don't have broken packages, because "apt-mark showhold" comes up empty.

Is there anything particular about installing ubuntu-sdk on Ubuntu 15.04 that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Remove the PPA, and install the SDK available by default in the repositories. I think that documentation is out of date, and if it has any use, is probably useful for 14.04 which has older packages.

Comment: @Akiva Thanks. I removed the PPA, ran an "apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade" and then an "apt-get install ubuntu-sdk". Still getting the same dependency problem and apt-get complains about me having held broken packages. Actually, I gave up on 15.04 and installed a 14.04 in VirtualBox. The SDK installs and runs fine on 14.04, but I still haven't checked if it can detect my phone from within the VM.

Comment: Yeah, Ive been down that road. The PPA mucked up quite a bit for me, and I ended up saving more time doing a reinstall, which is only about 30 minutes. Trick is, trying to find a good way to migrate the current settings over to that. Running 15.10 atm ; its quite stable.

Comment: I think that another PPA is needed too: ppa:phablet-team/tools

Answer (score 0):

your xorg-edgers ppa has been disabled while updating, add the repo again, update and upgrade, that should fix the issue.

---

So the issue is that the installed version of the libgles2-mesa package has a higher version than what is normally supported. 
My guess is that, before updating to 15.04, you had the xorg-edgers ppa which causes you to have this higher version. However, the update to 15.04 disabled this ppa, you can see if this is indeed the case by checking *software & updates* and then under the tab *Other Software* (you can type `software-properties-gtk` in the terminal to get there).

If this is the case then:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you also tell the OP (Original Poster) *how* to do this?  As it is now, theysystem will be deleting your answer soon for lack of quality...